# Titanium facebook login and logout

Tags: facebook, authentication, titanium, logout

i added my facebook login button to my login page which then re-directs users to the tabgroup. My question is; (instead of both fb login/logout button to be in the same page) how can i make the fb login button appear on the login page and then make the fb logout page appear in one of my tabs or another page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you could make the custom one

Here is the method

facebook login

```
 Ti.Facebook=Titanium.Facebook = require('facebook');
    Ti.Facebook.appid = FACEBOOK_APP_ID;
    Ti.Facebook.permissions = ['publish_stream']; // Permissions your app needs
    Ti.Facebook.forceDialogAuth = true;
    var btnLogin = Titanium.UI.createButton({
       title: 'Hello',
       top: 10,
       width: 100,
       height: 50
    });
    win.add(btnLogin);
    btnLogin.addEventListener('click',function(e)
    { 
    Ti.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert('Logged In');
        } else if (e.error) {
            alert(e.error);
        } else if (e.cancelled) {
            alert("Canceled");
        }
    });
    Ti.Facebook.authorize();
    });
```

and FB logout

```
    var btnLogout = Titanium.UI.createButton({
       title: 'Hello',
       top: 10,
       width: 100,
       height: 50
    });
    win2.add(btnLogout);
    btnLogout.addEventListener('click',function(e)
    {
     Ti.Facebook.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {
        alert('Logged out');
    });
    Ti.Facebook.logout();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: hello, Wahhab, i encountered a slight problem...the login button works fine but when i click on the logout button, it gives me an error - "can't find variable: fb at app.js" (on this line - fb.addEventListener('logout', function(e) {

Comment: yes plz try to make the mdoule part that i am accessing to global

Comment: pls can you explain more, i do not understand

Comment: still nothing. Couldn't log me out. Thanks for your help, if you come up with any other solution pls kindly explain to me.

Comment: which platform you are testing?